# Domain of this function:

Tags: calculus

$$g(x) = \frac{3x-2}  {\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}}$$

I know that the radicand can't be less than $0$, and the roots of the quadratic are $2$ and $3$ but I don't know how to express all this as a domain.

Comment: express as intervals or union of intervals by solving the inequality $x^2+5x+6=(x+2)(x+3)>0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Note that $x^2+5x+6 = (x+2)(x+3)$. I hope you know the fact that the $x^2+5x+6$ term in the denominator should not be less than or equal to zero (why?).

Then, $$(x+2)(x+3) > 0 \implies x \in \, ?$$

Comment: @allane You can accept my answer by checking the tick mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{x^2+ 5x+ 6}= \sqrt{(x+ 3)(x+ 2)}$$

You "cannot divide by $0$" so, immediately, $-2$ and $-3$ are not in the domain.

Further, assuming this is to be a real valued function, you "cannot take the square root of a negative number.  We must have $(x+ 3)(x+ 2)\ge 0$.  Look at $3$ intervals, $x< -3, -3< x< -2$, and $x> -2$.

If $x< -3$ then both $x+ 3$ and $x+ 2$ are negative so their product, $(x+ 3)(x+ 2)$ is positive.

If $-3< x< 2$ then $x+ 3$ is positive while $x+ 2$ is still negative.  $(x+ 3)(x+ 2)$ is negative.

If $x> -2$ then both $x+ 3$ and $x+ 2$ are positive  so $(x+ 3)(x+ 2)$ is positive.

The domain is all real numbers **except** $-3\le x\le -2$.

You don't say what notation you are to use but that domain can be written as $(-\infty, -3)\cup (-2, \infty)$ or as $\{ x| x< -3, x> -2\}$.  Or it could be written simply as $\{x | x^2+ 5x+ 6> 0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$x \in \mathbb{R}$

$D:=${ $x: (x+2)(x+3) >0$ }.

1)$ (x+2)(x+3) > 0.$

Both factors, $(x +2)$  and $(x+3)$, need to be positive for the product to be positive.

$x+2>0$; $x>-2;$. and:  $x+3 >0; x >-3;$

$\rightarrow$: $x>-2.$

2) Both factors, $(x+2)$ and: $ (x+3)$, need to be negative for the product to be positive.

$x+2<0;$ $x < -2;$   and:
$x+3 <0$; $x< -3; $

$\rightarrow:$ $x<-3.$

Combining:

$D= (-\infty, -3)\cup (-2,\infty).$